# Jenkins: Post build actions on conditions

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I want to run some post build actions in my Jenkins job on condition if a string or a regular expression is present in the console log. Any plugin available to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the [LogParser](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) plugin and to create some regexp rules to parse your log.

This plugin can change the build status to Unstable:

[image]

Next, you create a downstream job and you will use the [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin to pass the build status from the upstream to the downstream job.

If the status is unstable (= the LogParser find something), then you will execute some specific post build actions.

You can use the [Conditional BuildStep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin to condition the downstream build step according to the upstream build status.

Comment: Is this possible using Regular expression match in Conditional BuildStep?

Comment: Yes you can select "Regular expression match" as a condition.