# Using Groovy script to execute a post build action

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am running two ant targets in my build **compile**(source compilation) and **compile_tests**(tests compilation). In post build action I have added option to create **Mantis**(bug tracking tool) ticket on build failure. But I only want to create ticket when my build fails on compile target.

Is there a way to use groovy script as a condition for running post build actions? Or any other way to do this task?

Comment: is it possible to put two ant targets in two jenkins job, then it is more flexible to use other plugins ? and refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648224/jenkins-post-build-actions-on-conditions

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to condition an action in the groovy post build is using the Jenkins API to get the build result.

Code example (do something if build failed):

```
if (manager.build.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE) {
    // do you magic here 
}
```

I hope this helps.